# How to overwrite an overwrite with initial class in CSS?

Tags: css

I cannot edit CSS. I can only make an overwrite.

I have border:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], 
input[type="search"], input[type="url"], input[type="tel"], 
input[type="number"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], 
input[type="week"], input[type="time"], input[type="range"], 
input[type="color"], select, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8
}
```

Then it have an overwrite (which I can't edit):

```
.section_form input[type="email"], input[type="text"] {
    border: 0;
}
```

I'd like to cancel that overwrite and fall back to the first block of code. What would be best practice to do this?

@edit I'd like to make it dependent on initial class. So if it's border changes to `2px solid pink`, then `.section_form` inputs too.

Comment: You should make your selector more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the rule you want to override. But avoid at all costs using `!important`. You should also be able to create a selector identical to the one you want to override and load it after it which would override it.

Comment: @j08691 Sorry, forgot about selector. I added ".section_form"

Comment: You can't do this. Certainly not the second part, at least. Why can't you edit the other selector that overwrites the property? This sounds like a localized issue that should be solved with a person rather than programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

You can add `!important` to the end of the selector, like this.

```
input[type="text"], input[type="password"], input[type="email"], 
input[type="search"], input[type="url"], input[type="tel"], 
input[type="number"], input[type="date"], input[type="month"], 
input[type="week"], input[type="time"], input[type="range"], 
input[type="color"], select, textarea {
    border: 1px solid #e8e8e8 !important;
}
```

However, doing this a lot is considered by many to be bad practice. I would ask why you can't edit the more specific selector, as there may be a good reason it shouldn't be changed.